# USB barcode scanner reading incorrect values

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, scanner, emulation, barcode

We use an barcode reader. It runs on Ubuntu but reads different character.

example:

In barcode: 86912464
Ubuntu read as:  3~3~BDBCD

here is my xinput list

```
    ali@ali-samsung:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-13HDL12131N                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Scantech-ID BV Scantech-ID BV Mica Scanner Keyboard emulation id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: What kind of USB barcode reader are you using? I just wonder with a USB barcode reader, whether it will scan the barcode images from (for example Excel speadsheet) automatically, without any manual actions[.](http://www.barcodelib.com/net_barcode_reader/main.html)

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar problem with barcode reader. I ended up buying a wireless barcode reader from ebay which acts like a wireless keyboard. As such, the ubuntu doesnt have to have any special driver to interpret the barcode signal, instead, the barcode reader decipher the code and send it as text to the computer.

Here is a link to the barcode reader I bought:
[ebay wireless barcode scanner](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Free-Holder-New-Alanda-CT007S-2-4Ghz-Wireless-Wired-Laser-Barcode-Scanner-Reader-/121480262801?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c48c9b491)

Anyhow, I am still looking for ways for ubuntu to support a wired barcode scanner, it will be much more desirable (no need for charging) and more reliable (no wireless signal interference)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the barcode scanner correctly? There exist many different barcode types. I only know it for the [Honeywell](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/CatalogDocuments/00-02544%20Rev%20K%202-11.pdf) scanners we use, you configure them using pre-defined barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the barcode scanner scanning the manufacturer's special barcodes. After that it will work.

Try this code:

[image]

Source: http://69.195.82.78/sid/e-DM/DesktopScanner/MICA%20M-9080i/Default%20Barcode%20Card.pdf

---

Also check these special codes:

http://69.195.82.78/sid/e-DM/DesktopScanner/MICA%20M-9080i/Configuration%20Guide.pdf